# Showing an activity until user logs in

Tags: android, authentication, login-control

I have an activity where the user has to login first to see contents of the application. I want to show the activity till the user logs in/registers and then the activity must never be shown. How do I achieve this?

Comment: you can create a splash activity and you can check inside this splashactivity  a setting( for example "username" "password") and when its correct you can start the home activity

Answer (score 0):

You can make your main activity as your launch activity. In the onResume of your main activity, you check if the user is logged in. If not, you start your Login activity.

Comment: don´t do it in onResume() in onCreate() its got called much faster http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png

Comment: i would also suggest you to add a splashscreen https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

Comment: @Fabian : He didn't say he wants a splashcreen

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to [this tutorial](http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/showcase/2/) to learn how to create a splash activity/login activity. Then just consider making login activity as the starting one and process a check to see if user is already logged in or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if user is logged in the OnCreate method, if is correctly logged, then continue normally the activity. If he is not logged in, open new activity showing the login form and finish the previous one so he cant go back to the main activity without logging first.

Doing it this way you dont have to check in the onResume method if user is logged because if he isnt, activity would have been finished before going to the OnResume method.